# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' Python error while append

Tags: python, xml, csv, typeerror, csvreader

I am having a CSV file which contains a ordering of test cases and i have a xml file which is unordered and i am trying to order the xml file according to the csv file. While doing that i am getting this error:-

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-208-7ef10cfb792b> in <module>
     28     for TestCaseName in csv_order:
     29         try:
---> 30             children.append(tests.pop(TestCaseName))
     31         except KeyError:
     32             print(f"Test '{TestCaseName}' not present")

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Here is my code:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# Read in the XML and parse it

with open(r'example_xml/DM12_new.xml') as f_input:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_input, 'xml')

# Store all test tags in a dictionary

tests = {}

for test in soup.find_all('Test'):
    tests[test['Name']] = test

# Locate the children tag and empty it

children = soup.find('Children')
children.clear()

# Read in the ordering CSV and append the tests in the required order into
# the children tag

with open(r'csv/SPT.csv', newline='') as f_order:
    csv_order = csv.reader(f_order)
    header = next(csv_order)

    for TestCaseName in csv_order:
        try:
            children.append(tests.pop(TestCaseName))
        except KeyError:
            print(f"Test '{TestCaseName}' not present")

# Add any remaining tests not listed in the CSV

for test in tests.values():
    children.append(test)

# Write the modified XML

with open(r'example_xml/output.xml', 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(str(soup))
```

What is the problem here can someone help me to fix it? THanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
with open(r'csv/SPT.csv', newline='') as f_order:
    csv_order = csv.reader(f_order)
    header = next(csv_order)

    for TestCaseName in csv_order:
        try:
            children.append(tests.pop(TestCaseName))
        except KeyError:
            print(f"Test '{TestCaseName}' not present")
```

`TestCaseName` is holding all values from given row of csv file, is this your intention or it should be value from one of columns, for example `TestCaseName[0]` for 1st column?

Comment: TestCaseName is holding all values

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: @StackLifeOfMe so do keys of `tests` correspond to whole rows of your file?

Comment: I have multiple columns in csv for example Id, TestCaseName, Processing_time etc. What I am trying to do is that according to the TestCaseName column containing the test case name I want to use that column to sort the XML file. Xml file also contains the same names but in unordered way.

Comment: @StackLifeOfMe then you should probably grab correct column first, if TestCaseName is 2nd column replace `children.append(tests.pop(TestCaseName))` using `children.append(tests.pop(TestCaseName[1]))`

Comment: @StackLifeOfme `.csv` file you are reading